# PHP Check if date has passed (Not Working - Why?)

Tags: php, date, time, compare

I have just realised that when I validate a code, it shows valid all the time, even when the expiry date is old. Can someone see what I got wrong.

Just not getting it...

```
{
    $status = "<p8>ERROR</p8>";
    $entity_name = $rowa['entity_name'];
    $cert_no = $rowa['cert_no'];
    $issue_num = $rowa['issue_num'];
    $level = $rowa['level'];
    //$issue_date = $rowa['issue_date'];
    $issue_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($rowa['issue_date']));
    //$expiry_date = $rowa['expiry_date'];
    $expiry_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($rowa['expiry_date']));
    //$status = $rowa['status'];
    $date_time = date("d-m-Y");
    if($date_time < $expiry_date)
    {
        $status = "<p8>Valid</p8>";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "<p9>In-Valid</p9>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the unix timestamp instead. Much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `date` you are converting the dates into strings - and because you are using a `'d-m-y'` format, they aren't compared in the way you think they are.

A quick and dirty solution is to reverse the format and use `'Ymd'` which will return them in format like `20130905` which WILL work as a string comparison, but the better method is to create them in an actual [date time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) format or a timestamp via something like `mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);`

Answer (score 1):

transform the dates to compare in unixtime with mktime

Comment: While this is correct, it is generally a good to include an example of how to do so when answering questions on SO, or at least provide a link to a more detailed explanation of what you are talking about. You are correct here, but this isn't much of an answer as it is.